# Make haskell function accepts itself as parameters

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning haskell, trying to make a function `successor` either takes in a `Num` and returns its successor (`4 == successor 3`) or takes in itself and returns a double successor function (`5 == (successor successor) 3`).

What would be the correct way to make `successor` function is a type of its class `Successor`?

naive `Successor` class

```hs
class Successor a where
    successor :: a -> a


instance Successor Int where
    successor n
        | (==) 1 n = 2
        | otherwise = 1 + successor (n - 1)
```

test code

```hs
n :: Int
n = 3
m = successor (successor n)

main = do
    print m -- print 5
```

needed behavior

```hs
n :: Int
n = 3
m = (successor successor) n

main = do
    print m -- print 5
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `successor successor` instead of `successor . successor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems an awful idea to me -- why do you want to write a function working on both numbers and functions?

Anyway, you could achieve what you ask (but probably not what you really want) as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Main where

class Successor a where
    successor :: a -> a

instance Successor Int where
    successor n
        | (==) 1 n = 2
        | otherwise = 1 + successor (n - 1)

instance Successor (Int -> Int) where
    successor f = f . f

n' :: Int
n' = 3

m1 :: Int
m1 = successor (successor n')

m2 :: Int
m2 = (successor successor) n'

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print m1 -- print 5
    print m2 -- print 5
```

The definition `successor f = f . f` works in this specific case, where `f = successor`, but will likely not produce the expected output in other cases.

We could use some variant like `successor f = successor . f`. Perhaps this is more useful in general, but it still looks as a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with chi that this is probably a bad idea, but if you're going to have such a typeclass then I'd make it as general as possible:

```
class Successor a where
  scs :: a -> a

instance Successor Int where
  scs = succ  -- don't reinvent the wheel

instance Successor a => Successor (c -> a) where
  scs f = scs . f
```

Then

```
ghci> scs scs (scs (scs scs)) ((scs scs) scs) scs (scs scs) 0 :: Int
11
```

Comment: This is the [`Ap (c ->) a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap) pattern, and it can be derived if you implement the general pattern `deriving via Ap ((->) c) a instance Successor a => Successor (c -> a)`